# JavaScript: Calculating 3 parcel sizes based on order quantity

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to work out the best solution for selecting the most suitable parcel size(s) based on the total number of items ordered.

For example, there are 3 parcel sizes.

- Small Parcel can hold 6 items
- Medium Parcel can hold 12 items
- Large Parcel can hold 24 items

I'm trying to work out the best possible way to calculate how many and of what size parcel(s) would be required. If the user orders any number of items below 24, the calculation is easy with an `if statement`, but if they were to order 28 items as an example, the function needs to calculate that a `Small Parcel` & `Large Parcel` would be required.

Does anyone has any advice or can point me in the right direction about the best way to approach this?

Comment: Google modulo calculation (`%`).

Comment: This is a question about an algorithm, not a particular language.

Comment: You can work out how many large parcels you can fit it in i.e `n / 24`. With the remainder i.e. `n % 24` you just repeat the process for the smaller parcels. You will have situations e.g 31 where it wont fit into the provided parcel sizes exactly, for this could just allow for small parcels that aren't completely full.

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, mark the correct answer. If not, comment on the answers given and elaborate on why your question is not answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a first approach for an algorithm:

```js
let order = 89;
let packageSizes = [12, 6, 24];

// make sure packageSizes have descending order [ 24, 12, 6 ]
packageSizes.sort((a,b)=>b-a);

let packages = packageSizes.map(size => {
  let res = [ Math.floor(order/size), order % size ];
  order = res[1];
  return (
    size === packageSizes[packageSizes.length-1] 
      ? res[1] 
        ? res[0] + 1 
        : res[0] 
      : res[0]
  )
})

console.log(packages);
```

When the algorithm is done, `packages` contains the number of large, medium and small parcels in that order.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was trying to look up. I'll do some more reading on modulo but this was the exact direction I needed. Appreciate it!